# Docker can't give permission to script in entrypoint

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy a docker image on my rpi3+ (arm7). The entrypoint script work when run manually, but I cant manage to make it work directly in the dockerfile. I always get this error:
Permision denied : Unknow

Heres my docker.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-bionic-arm32v7
WORKDIR /SenseAI.CollectionAgent
COPY /s .
USER root
CMD /bin/bash -c 'chmod +x /SenseAI.CollectionAgent/run.sh'
ENTRYPOINT ["/SenseAI.CollectionAgent/run.sh"]
```

The path of the file seems right.
I have tried so many different commands, but none worked.
The content of my run.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x #echo on
apt-get update
apt-get install libreadline-dev -y
chmod +x Gateway/SenseaiZ3Gateway
dotnet SenseAI.CollectionAgent.dll
```

but I think the error really comes from launching run.sh

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the `chmod` command in `RUN` Directive:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-bionic-arm32v7
WORKDIR /SenseAI.CollectionAgent
COPY /s .
USER root
RUN chmod +x /SenseAI.CollectionAgent/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/SenseAI.CollectionAgent/run.sh"]
```

Comment: I tried this, but the pipeline seems to change the command to
 bin/sh -c chmod +x /SenseAI.CollectionAgent/run.sh' and it crash